# Aplicação Android fecha ao se conectar com o MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, android, servidor

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para o Android da qual necessita se conectar com meu banco de dados no servidores da Locaweb. Porém, conforme está no código, a classe fecha caso ela não consiga se conectar ao servidor. Será que estou realizando a conexão de forma errada?

Segue o código da classe:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Desenvolvido por Willian Fernando da Cunha a partir 22/10/2015.
 */

public class Recupera extends ActionBarActivity {

private String jsonResult;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Lista> customList;
private ListView lv;
private String url = "URL DO SITE(NÃO DIVULGADO)";
private String[] prices;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recupera);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean connected = ni != null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    if(connected){
        if(ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            //Carrega conteúdo.
            startWebService();
        }else{
            DialogMessageDisplay.displayWifiSettingsDialog(Recupera.this, Recupera.this, "Você está desconectado!", "Erro ao carregar. Por favor, verifique sua conexão com a internet.", AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
        }

    }
}



public class JsonReadTast extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    public JsonReadTast(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Recupera.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Aguarde...");
        pDialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try{
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Recupera.this.finish();
        }
        return null;

    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is){
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try{
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                answer.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Recupera.this.finish();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        ListDrawer();
        pDialog.dismiss();
        }
}//Finaliza a task de Async.

public void startWebService(){
    JsonReadTast task = new JsonReadTast();
    task.execute(new String[]{url});
}

private void ListDrawer() {
    customList = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMain = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");
        for(int i=0; i<jsonMain.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonChild = jsonMain.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = jsonChild.optString("name");
            String price = jsonChild.optString("price");
            String image = jsonChild.optString("image");
            String prices1 = jsonChild.getString("price1");
            String prices2 = jsonChild.getString("price2");
            String prices3 = jsonChild.getString("price3");
            String prices4 = jsonChild.getString("price4");

            prices = new String[]{prices1, prices2, prices3, prices4};

            customList.add(new Lista(name, price, image, prices));
        }
    }catch (Exception ee){
        Recupera.this.finish();
    }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new Atualizador(Recupera.this, R.layout.list_items, customList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Recupera.this.finish();
}
```

A chamada a `Recupera.this.finish()` dentro da excepção faz terminar a Activity `Recupera` quando existe algum erro. Dentro do bloco try-catch deve tratar o erro de forma adequada aquilo que está a fazer no momento. Neste caso específico, pode implementar um aviso ao utilizador quando correr mal o pedido.
Outra coisa que não está muito bem é o `catch(Exception e)`. Não se deve apanhar excepções desta maneira. Tem de ser mais granular e apanhar apenas aquelas que podem ser disparadas pelo bloco de código dentro do `try`.